# Simple PerformancePoint KPI for counting rows?

Tags: performancepoint

I have a SQL table (or a BDC list if it's easier) that I would like to have a count of certain values. There is one column I want to see how many of each value are in the table. Everything I've seen for PerformancePoint is totaling (sum) of columns, how can I just report on filtered counts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on your Data Source under your Data Connections in Dashboard Designer.

Go to the View tab and click the column you want to have counted. Under the details pane you can change the Aggregation, the default is Sum, click the drop down list and you should have Count there.

Answer (score 2):

Does that solution work for external lists as well?  If not, here's a solution done with a SQL View:

```
-- Create a view that will combine all of my rows that were inserted on the same date and
-- provide a column with the number of other rows with that date

select day_of_submission, sum(1) as [Count]
from my_table 
group by day_of_submission
```